# When starting writing a website from scratch, what do I do in order to enable a "publishing format"?

Tags: html, blogs

I am planning on building my own website from scratch. However, I want it to be in a blog from. I have designed the template/design but before I started the whole writing process, I was wondering: How do you publish posts onto the blog itself?

Let's say I have settled on Github as my web host. After building the website, how will I publish posts? Do I have to implement Wordpress/Blogger into the mix? Because I really want to build this website myself, I was trying to stray away from "pre-made" platforms. However, I was wondering if I could update the website with posts via Github.

Sorry if there are terms that I haven't used properly, I am still new at this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-made blog platforms will be way less hassle in the long term, but let's ignore that for now.

It sounds like you have a front-end going and that's fine. What you want is some way to administer the blog. You could do this a bunch of ways, and since you're only writing this for yourself the most convenient way for you personally is the best one to go for.

First and foremost you need some kind of datasource for the blog frontend to pull from. You'd generally have an array of blog posts which would contain a title, a body, time it was posted, etc. The data the posts contain is up to you entirely.

The most common way of doing this is to use a database. You could just as easily do it a whole bunch of other ways though.

Just having a data source is only half the solution however, you'll also want something that can insert data, and modify existing data.

Just a few potential solutions off the top of my head are:

- Store blog posts as markdown files in a directory and edit them manually
- Write an admin backend that administers the blog posts and store them in a database
- Use the datasource from another application (like a mail server or a git repo or something) to manage the data, and pull the data from that into your frontend.
- Rather than use a data source, simply have a bunch of static pages and have the portion of the page above and below a blog post as mixins that your page renderer includes, and manually update the post index/front page as needed.

I think the first solution would be easiest/best, or a combination of the first two would be ideal.